# Azure Mobile Service query returns all lower case column name in JSON

Tags: azure-mobile-services

I am new to Azure Mobile services.  I noticed that whenever I used Azure online tools(in manage.windowsazure.com) to create a new column name for a table, it always turns my uppercase column name into lowercase. (for eample: I typed FullName for a column name, but it became fullname).

Now, if I used angular-azure-mobile-service to query data, it returns "fullname" in JSON format.  Such as {'fullname': 'ABC Inc'}.

Is there anyway I can have the Json return be formatted as {'FullName':..} instead?

Answer (score 2):

The column names for Azure Mobile Services are case insensitive, so we transform them to ensure there is no confusion.  This should be completely separate from display issues.  If you are worried about display, wrap the JSON in another object that transforms it appropriately.